# Authentication errors when using build server

Tags: unity, build-process, automation, jenkins

This is my build command:

```
-nographics  "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.23f1" -batchmode -quit -executeMethod JenkinsBuild.BuildAndroid -username xxxx -password xxxx    -manualLicenseFile  C:\ProgramData\Unity\Unity_lic.ulf  -force-free -logfile
```

But I get these error logs:

```
Entitlement-based licensing initiated
[Licensing::Module]  Error: Access token is unavailable; failed to update
[LicensingClient] Error: Code 200 while updating license in client (status: Licenses updated.)
[Licensing::Module] Loading manual activation license file C:\ProgramData\Unity\Unity_lic.ulf.
[LicensingClient] Error: Code 400 while processing request (status: Machine bindings don't match)
```

Comment: It could be anything based on the information given. Please include the details of the environment and your setup.